# F1 does not work in my Excel-VBA, how can I fix?

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I'm new to VBA, so being able to use the help feature is important to me. Right now, whenever I highlight something, or place my cursor inside of it, and press F1 I get this generic help screen:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/top-help-topics-029f9370-e2e3-4639-9c23-b46b1b8d5230?lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL&Version=90&ShowNav=False&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

I have this issue no matter what I try to highlight. I have a university account, but that isn't the issue because F1 Help works with the same account on my laptop (the issue is with my desktop). I just updated to the latest version and the problem still persists so that can't be it either. The only thing I could think of is that my PC doesn't have wi-fi capabilities (im hooked up via ethernet) and my laptop does.

If anyone has idea please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1134103/52365 (not too helpful though).

Comment: @gserg yeah ive seen that exact thread. TBH though, I dont know how to fork/clone and I'm not sure if that actually works or not